# Power BI to Acumatica Connection

Tags: ms-office, powerbi, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am having errors while trying to connect Power BI to my Acumatica. I am not sure if it is no set up correctly in Acumatica itself or if I am doing it wrong altogether. I have followed a lot of the steps I have found on the web. Some examples of these would be Tim Rodman and Microsoft. The errors I get when I try to log into Acumatica app on Power BI:

- *Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed: 
  OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an
  error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found) OData Version: 4, Error: The
  remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found) OData
  Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
  Found. (Not Found)*
- Error #2: There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.
  Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
  MessageThe column 'Created' of the table wasn't found.
- There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.
  Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
  MessageThe key didn't match any rows in the table.
  Activity IDc718a6b5-154d-4691-8896-f4a328acf95e
  Correlation ID44788a32-ef31-8554-0c50-c5f36aa3f730
  Request IDb76f990c-4581-6f0a-4a28-d77115d25747
  Status code400
  TimeFri Nov 16 2018 09:40:27 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
  Version13.0.7382.141
  Cluster URIhttps://wabi-us-east2-redirect.analysis.windows.net

I get error #2 and #3 when I changed the url to have to the companyName at the end instead of just https://[sitedomain]/odata/. Error #2 url = https://[sitedomain]/odata/[companyname].

Any ideas will help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL # 2 is formatted in the same way that worked for me.

To resolve your problem I would suggest you back up a little and troubleshoot each step along the way.

1) Can you connect to your instance in Power BI and get a list of OData sources?
If you can then your connection string and credentials are correct. If not this is where your issue is.

2) If you create a new query against one of the OData sources listed in (1) does it retrieve the data?

If it does then it suggests to me that your issue is within the query(s) you have created.

Without more details that's the best suggestion I can make.